ResourceRegistrationFailureException when provisioning using JITP
I'm following the JITP workflow as described in this AWS blog post:Setting Up Just-in-Time Provisioning with AWS IoT Core.
Steps I've Taken:

Generated the root CA certificate.
Registered the CA certificate in AWS IoT Core.
Created the provisioning template.

{
             "Parameters": 
         {
              "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id": {
              "Type": "String"
          },
               "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country": {
               "Type": "String"
          }
         },
         "Resources": {
             "thing": {
              "Type": "AWS::IoT::Thing",
              "Properties": {
                   "ThingName": {
                    "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id"
                },
               "AttributePayload": {
                      "version": "v1",
                      "country": {
                      "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country"
                }
                }
              }
            },
            "certificate": {
            "Type": "AWS::IoT::Certificate",
            "Properties": {
            "CertificateId": {
            "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id"
             },
             "Status": "ACTIVE"
             }
             },
             "policy": {
      "Type": "AWS::IoT::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "iot:Connect",
              "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "iot:Publish",
              "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
              "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "iot:Receive",
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Problem: Whenever I try to connect using the device certificate and key, I always get an unsuccessful result.
Observations: In the AWS Console under IoT Core > Certificates, I see the certificate is generated but has a status of pending_activation. In CloudWatch, the error code is ResourceRegistrationFailureException. It appears that the thing is not being registered, nor is the policy being attached.
Question: Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong or missing in my setup? Any advice on how to successfully register the thing and attach the policy would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
